# Is scooter rental in Philippines as common among tourists as it is in Thailand?

Tags: rental, philippines, scooters

While I was traveling in Thailand last year I rented a scooter on multiple occasions which gave me new dimensions of freedom. Scooter rent shops were abundant.

In a month I'll be travelling to Philippines and would like to explore the hidden roads the same way but when looking (online) for a bike rental in Baguio (which has 300k population) the resources were scarce and the most common comment was that it's better to rent a bike in Angeles City and drive it north which I would like to avoid.

So what is the situation in known tourist areas such as Boracay, Palawan, Banaue and others? Is scooter renting widely available or hard to find?

Comment: You are aware that safety in the Philippines is not as good as in Thailand? I am talking about personal safety. Theft, violence, combination of both.. So do not take your experience in Thailand and apply it in the Philippines

Comment: By what metric would you measure popularity? And what relevance does the relative popularity have to travel or your plans? I think you asked the wrong question.

Comment: @Heidel, I understand that and will take necessary security precautions.
Flimzy, you know when you're somewhere in Thailand - almost anywhere where tourists go - and you see quite a few westerners on scooters? And every little town has it's own rent shop? I mean by this metric.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me answer my own question. I just got back from the trip and I found out that motorbike rental shops are abundant in Philippines (but usually not advertised online) . The price is usually about 600PHP (12 USD) for one day. 
Even in rural places where there are no renting businesses it is easy to arrange for a rental with locals.

I rented 6 different motorbikes throughout the country and had no problem whatsoever.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can find a bike rental in most any city you're in.  Just remember to bring a separate ID when renting.  They will require you leave one with them and you don't want to leave your drivers license.